# Oracle sql join with case when

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a master-detail situation like this one
Details of header:

```
pk | desc | quantity | fkHeader
1  | AA   | 10       |  1
2  | BB   | -50      |  1
3  | CC   | 25       |  1
```

I need to extract first the rows with negative quantity then with positive
So I thought to use a cursor and pass it the sign number ('+' o '-') as parameter

something like this

```
cursor rec (p_sign in char) is
  select * 
    from details
   where (case when p_sign = '+' then quantity > 0 else quantity < 0 end)
```

And get something like this

> (rec with '+')

```
1 | AA | 10 | 1
3 | CC | 25 | 1
```

> (rec with '-')

```
2 | BB | -50 | 1
```

But this of course doesn't work..couldn't extract rows switching on parameter value

Is there a way to use a the case as where condition (or JOIN) or I need two separated cursors?

Thank you

Comment: It's generally better to use `AND`/`OR` instead of `case` expressions in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Do you simply want `ORDER BY quantity`?

Comment: what do you want to achieve?

Comment: Hello, no, I need to extract first the rows with negative quantity then those positive
And I'd like to know if it's possibile doing with a single cursor (instead of two separated explicting saying quantiy > 0 and the second quantity <0) using a parameter..

Comment: Not an expert in oracle SQL,but did you give a try to something like `SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE quantity < 0 ORDER BY pk UNION SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE quantity >= 0 ORDER BY pk` ?

Comment: Mike please check my answer. I have included variety of examples. I am not sure about your goal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your procedure solution (passing a variable) is not the best way to solve this, however to answer the questions specifically about the SQL contained inside the proc I've written here. Again, ultimately the better solution for your *actual* question is a single sql statement with a proper order by.

You can't return a condition in a case expression. Instead you would need to get a little tricky here:

```
WHERE CASE WHEN p_sign='+' THEN quantity ELSE quantity * -1 END < 0
```

However it would be clearer if you used `and`/`or` logic as suggested by @jarlh in the comments:

```
WHERE ((p_sign='+' AND quantity > 0) OR (p_sign<>'+' AND quantity < 0))
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this works for you?

```
select * from tbl
order by case when quantity > 0 then 1 else 0 end;
```

If you need them seperately

```
select * from tbl where quantity < 0;
select * from tbl where quantity >=0;
```

you can also union them

```
select * from tbl where quantity < 0 union
select * from tbl where quantity >=0;
```

you can also mark them like

```
select 
  case when quantity < 0 then '-' else '+' end sign, 
  tbl.* 
from tbl
```

then

```
select * from 
(
  select 
    case when quantity < 0 then '-' else '+' end sign, 
    tbl.* 
  from tbl 
) 
order by sign
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for answering.
This one is just an order by

Comment: Thank you. I included it

Comment: Thank you both guys..i can't choose both and thank you too Simonare for helping me

Answer (score 0):

Your basic idea will work, you just use appropriate AND/OR logic instead of CASE:

```
cursor rec (p_sign in char) is
  select * 
    from details
   where (p_sign = '+' AND quantity > 0) OR (p_sign = '-' AND quantity < 0)
```